# jQuery plugin option as a css property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a plugin that accepts options when it is called. However, I want one of the options to also double up as a css property (position)

```
var settings = $.extend({
        position : 'right',
        size     : '300px',
        speed    : '1000ms'
}, options );

if (settings.position == 'left' || settings.position == 'right') {
       return this.css({
           width: settings.size,
           height: '100%',
           settings.position: '-' + settings.size
       });
}
```

I want the `settings.position: '-' + settings.size` to effectively output: `right: -300px`.

Thanks

Comment: with ES6 you can use `{height : '100%', [settings.position] : '-' + settings.size}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var css = {
    width: settings.size,
    height: '100%'
};

css[settings.position] = '-' + settings.size;

return this.css(css);
```

This way the interpreter will evaluate `settings.position` into a string first, causing the expression to become `css['left'] = ...`